# ActiveRecord: class methods without scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, class-method

I need to create a class method of my ActiveRecord.
But that method is not meant to be a scope, so I'd like to prevent misusage of it like a scope.
Is it possible to do?

Comment: You **can** create class methods by `def self.your_method_name` and mark it `private`.

Comment: Thanks. But I need them to be public.

Comment: Then IMHO, it is also prone to whatever misuse, you fear with a scope.

Answer (score 1):

Like kiddorails hinted, this is not possible.  The underlying reason is that AR puts many responsibilities into one class -- validation, persistence, finding/querying.  If you really care about encapsulating these methods in one place, then you might consider creating a separate class (which would prevent 'misuse' by nature as it only has query-related methods) that handles just the query-related logic.  (There are other strategies one could consider as well, too)